# javascript make url read only

Tags: extjs

I work with extjs 3.4

I have this kind of code :

```
var url = "/group/supcom/hiddenpages/tracking?selector=" + id_corresp;  
location = url;
```

I want to know is it possible   to make this URL   **read only**

maning  when this URL for example :

```
http://com.supcom:8080/group/supcom/hiddenpages/tracking?selector=CO-57250
```

is displayed  the user can not modify same characters in this url

Comment: A user can always change the url in their browser. It is impossible for you to stop them from doing that, and it would be very bad if a website could do that.

Comment: I work with a web application in JEE
I have a problem of hacking ,   same user change fo example in the URL  the value of selector  , they make CO-5555, as a result they can consult another interface related to this new value of selector ,   to stop them   for me the best way it is forbidden to change the url


I tried without success

Comment: I tried without success with location.readOnly=true;

Comment: You can't do it. You'll need to think of another method.

Comment: is it possible to send the url with post method
so the parameters are not displayed in the URL

Comment: It sounds like you need a way to restrict access to specific pages.